# Can't see the power options icon in the notification area

Tags: windows-8, power, icons, notification-area

I've formatted my windows 8  64 bit laptop, and encountered the following issue:
The power options icon won't show up. I tried adding it manually, but it shows the massage "This notification icon is not currently active." in the "Notification Area Icons" window. I also tried changing it via the "System Icons", but it's set to a grayed out "off".

How can i get the power options icon back to my notification area in the task bar?